# Windows 10 FT_OpenEx() API open error when insert/remove other USB device

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, usbserial, ftdi

We have device ""FT245R USB FIFO" USB to Seriel for communication from Windows 10 using D2xx driver.

FT_OpenEx() API works without any issue. But *whenever user unplug/plug new USB device(Mass storage device) , during that time FT_OpenEx() API failed to execute*, so handle invalid and our data communication interepted. Could you let us know what can I do further to resolve this issue ?

**Note:** I have opened handle using following command  FT_OpenEx("FT245R USB FIFO", FT_OPEN_BY_DESCRIPTION, &handle), I open it everytime, whenever I need to talk with communication device. tried with *seriel number* of the device , but still communication fails when unplug/plug other USB device.

Comment: So you really open and close the handle everytime you run the communication? Typically one get the handle only once and keep it alive until the program is done. Is there a reason to close the handle inbetween?

Comment: Yes, I was opening and closing everytime I access the device, I have changed to opening the handle at the begining of the applciation initialization and close while application closes. Which resolved my issue. Thanks